# Find general correlation between function with itself and other input data

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, neural-networks, intraclass-correlation

- I've collected data for a function `F = f(g(x))`, for different function shapes `g(x)`.
- The goal is to predict values of `F` for general case, i.e. for arbitrary `g(x)`.
- It's know that function derivative `dF/dx` depends on history of development of `dF/dx` and `g(x)` (and maybe `dg/dx`); this connection is something I would like to inspect based on the collected data

In this case, which are possible techniques for finding correlations, i.e. mathematical connectivity between `dF/dx` and other variables?

*Edit*: Imagine you have pipes in which water flows. For these pipes of different shapes I have pressure data in each location. Pressure at location depends on its history and pipe shape. I'd like to find pressure correlation laws based on all variables available.

Comment: This may be too abstract to be answerable here. Can you add some context & example data?

Comment: You seem to have accidentally created a second account, which limits your ability to edit your own post. [See here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge them.